# Action Script 3. Timer appears after 1 second

Tags: flash, actionscript, timer, action, show

I'm creating flash game and here are timer which shows how long player is playing on current level. Problem is that when game starts here is no timer, It appears only after 1 second and then It shows 00:01 second. I need to make that when game starts timer appeared immediately and show 00:00.

Here is my main Function.

```
public function MemoryGame()
        {
            addChild(CardContainer);
            tryAgain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, darKarta);
                timer = new Timer(1000); //create a new timer that ticks every second.
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick, false, 0, true); //listen for the timer tick
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, resetTimer);
                txtTime = new TextField();
                addChild(txtTime);

                tmpTime = timer.currentCount;
                timer.start();

            _cards = new Array();
            _totalMatches = 18;
            _currentMatches = 0;
            createCards();
        }
```

Here is my timer:

```
        private function tick(e:Event):void {
           txtTime.text = showTimePassed(timer.currentCount - tmpTime);                 


}
function showTimePassed(startTime:int):String {

  var leadingZeroMS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the miliseconds
  var leadingZeroS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the seconds
  var leadingZeroM:String = "";

  var time = getTimer() - startTime; //this gets the amount of miliseconds elapsed
  var miliseconds = (time % 1000); // modulus (%) gives you the remainder after dividing, 

  if (miliseconds < 10) { //if less than two digits, add a leading 0
    leadingZeroMS = "0";
  }

  var seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60); //this gets the amount of seconds

  if (seconds < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
    leadingZeroS = "0";
  }

  var minutes = Math.floor((time / (60 * 1000) ) );
    if (minutes < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
    leadingZeroM = "0";
  }
  //60 seconds times 1000 miliseocnds gets the minutes
  return leadingZeroM + minutes + ":" + leadingZeroS + seconds + "" + leadingZeroMS ;



}
```

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TextField` isn't initialized, and only will get updated when the `Timer` fires. The first time the timer will fire is at 1 second, so the first value to appear in the `TextField` is the same.

If you initialize your TextField with the starting value, your code should probably work fine:

```
txtTime = new TextField();
addChild(txtTime);
// set the start time here w/whatever is appropriate
textTime.text = showTimePassed(0);

tmpTime = timer.currentCount;
timer.start();
```